# Parsing Multiple NSMutableURLRequests with NSXMLParser at Once

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser, nsmutableurlrequest

I am using NSHTTPURLRequest to retrieve an XML string from a remote server and then using NSXMLParser to parse the XML. I have two different pieces of XML that I am retrieving, and parsing one of them by itself works fine; however when I try to append one request to the end of the other it parses the first, but it doesn't recognize the second tag.

My callbacks are as follows.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didRecieveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)resonse {
    if([[condition that is only true on the first run]])
        _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didRecieveData:(NSData *)data{
    [_repsonseData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection {
    if([[condition that is only true on the second run]])
        XMLParser *parser = [self invokeParser:_responseData];
    else
        [self doSecondRequest];
}

-(XMLParser*)invokeParser:(NSData*)data {
    NSXMLParser *nsParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] init];
    XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] init];
    [nsParser setDelegate:parser];
    [nsParser parse];
}
```

I invoke the NSMutableURLRequest twice in a row and boht complete successfully, I can dump the correct XML using NSLog just before I call invokeParser, but the parser never finds the second set of XML. The structure of the XML is as follows, where tags 1, 2, and 3 are from the first request and tag 4 is returned by the second request.

```
<tag 1>
  <tag 2>
    <tag 3 />
  </tag 2>
  <tag 2>
    <tag 3 />
  </tag 2>
  <tag 2>
    <tag 3 />
  </tag 2>
</tag 1>
<tag 4 />
```

With the two together like this the NSXMLParser callback for `didStartElement` is invoked for all of the tags EXCEPT tag 4. Both sets of XML work fine by themselves however. Does anyone know why this is?